# Text color in QPlainTextEditor - appendHtml

Tags: html, qt

```
void writeToEditor( QString partOfText, double readBytes )
    {
        QString combineHtml = "";

        for( int j = 0; j < readBytes; j++)
        {
            if(partOfText[j] == 'A')
            {
                combineHtml.append(QString("<div style='color: red;'>") + QString(partOfText[j]) +  QString("</div>"));
            }
            else
            {
                combineHtml.append(QString("<div style='color: blue;'>") + QString(partOfText[j]) +  QString("</div>"));
            }
        }

       objQPlainTextEdit.appendHtml( combineHtml );
  }
```

`objQPlainTextEdit` is the object of QPlainTextEdit.

This code is able to change the colors of the alphabets individually but the result is that each alphabet is displayed on a separate line.

I want it to be displayed together like a paragraph. I think the tag div has something to do with it.

How to write the `div` or `p` tag such that the result is a paragraph rather than individual characters?

Comment: Isn't that more a question about HTML and styling than Qt or C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp
This link shows how span tag can be used to put the words together.

Below is the working code:

```
    QString combineHtml = "<p>";

    for( int j = 0; j < readBytes; j++)
    {
        if( partOfText[j] == 'A' )
        {
            combineHtml.append( QString( "<span style = 'color: red'>")
                + QString( partOfText[j]) +  QString( "</span>"));
        }
        else
        {
            combineHtml.append( QString( "<span style = 'color: blue'>")
                + QString( partOfText[j]) +  QString( "</span>"));
        }
    }

  combineHtml.append( "</p>");
  
  std::cout << combineHtml.toStdString();
  
  objQPlainTextEdit.appendHtml( combineHtml );
```

Here `partOfText` is `QString`, and `objQPlainTextEdit` is an object of `QPlainTextEdit`.

Output generated by the above code is as follows:

```
<p><span style = 'color: blue'>C</span><span style = 'color: red'>A</span><span style = 'color: red'>A</span><span style = 'color: blue'>T</span><span style = 'color: blue'>C</span><span style = 'color: blue'>T</span><span style = 'color: blue'>C</span><span style = 'color: blue'>C</span><span style = 'color: red'>A</span><span style = 'color: blue'>T</span></p>
```

[image]